# Explanation of notations

Tags: group-theory, homology-cohomology

I was reading [Binary icosahedral group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_icosahedral_group) in Wikipedia. The author uses $\langle 2,3,5 \rangle$ and $(2,3,5)$ to denote the groups. And the Coxeter group of type $H_4$ is denoted by $[3,3,5]$. Could anyone explain to me the meaning of these notations? Many thanks

Comment: My guess is that the <2,3,5> and (2,3,5) notation is coming from the given presentations of the groups, whereas [3,3,5] is the *Schläfli symbol* for the associated 4-dimensional polytope.

Comment: @DerekHolt, now I know that $(2,3,5)$ is the notation from triangle group: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_group.